# clearInterval logic issue?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myVar = setInterval(fn, 2000)   
}
function fn() {
    alert("test")
    clearInterval(myVar)
}
```

The intention of the above is for it to perform the line alert("test") once and only once.
The end result of the above is an endless loop of alerts. 
Where am I going logically wrong?

Addition:

Further, the following results in an endless loop of alerts also. Is var myVar available to the highlightTotals() function? Is the issue here that it isn't?

```
var myVar;
window.onload = function() {
    var rbs = document.getElementsByName("rbToggle")
    for (i=0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
        rbs[i].addEventListener("click", highlightTotals)
    }
}
function highlightTotals() {
    myVar = setInterval(fn, 1000)
}
function fn() {
    alert("test")
    clearInterval(myVar)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myVar` is out of the scope of your `clearInterval` call.

Replace:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myVar = setInterval(fn, 2000)   
}   // myVar is only accessible within this function's scope.
```

With:

```
var myVar;
window.onload = function() {
    myVar = setInterval(fn, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and concise response.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting this answer when the 15-minute cooldown expires ;-)

Comment: I'm building up the code in phases. I think I've addressed the scope issue now, but the second piece of code above also results in an infinite loop of alerts. Is this because it can't access var myVar from within the function highlightTotals() where that's the specific piece of javascript being called by using the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Javascript are function scoped. They exist at the level of the function.

In your case here the variable `myVar` exists at the scope of the anonymous function you've passed to the window.onload handler, and not outside of it.

Moving your `myVar` variable outside of that function will allow you to use it in your `clearInterval` call.